# Single ASP.NET Identity for multiple projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2

Is there any way to use the ASP.NET Identity mechanism over two different projects?? ie. I want to use a single authentication mechanism for a MVC project and a WebAPI project. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure it is; extract the Identity portion into its own project and use it in both projects.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing difficult about this. If using boiler-plate MVC 5 templates make sure both are referencing the Owin pipeline and are using the same authentication type/provider (usually in `Startup.Auth.cs`).

If deploying to multiple web servers you will need to make sure your web.config's all share the same machineKey property.

An architecture I favour is to have a web project per user role.

For example

**myproject.sln**
— **Auth.csproj** (unauthorized)
— **Profile.csproj** (project has "AuthorizeAttribute" as default. All roles can access. Add `filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());` in `FilterConfig.cs`)
— **CustomRole.csproj** (project has custom "MyCustomRoleAttribute" derived from AuthorizeAttribute added in similar way as above.)

Comment: Could you please clarify:
1. referencing the Owin pipeline (where should I look?)
2. using the same authentication type/provider (what does this look like in Startup.Auth.cs?)